# QGIS misidentifying fields attribute type

Tags: qgis, labeling, fields-attributes, expression

In trying to build a simple expression to sum data into clusters I've used the following statement:

```
sum('MTO heat map_Total','MTO heat map_Grouping')
```

The value 'MTO heat map_Total' is an integer shown here:
[image: Field attribute type]

However the expression editor identifies the following error:
[image: String value instead of integer]

I'm not overly skilled with the program (yet) and I'm sure there is something I'm overlooking.
Any thoughts here?

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes `'` are for strings, double `"` for fields. So you are trying to sum the strings `'MTO heat map_total'` and `'MTO heat map grouping'`. Change `'` to `"` so QGIS understand you are referring to the fields

Comment: Or just skip any kind of quotes. You can refer to fields either using double quotes `"field_name"` or just the field's name: `field_name`. To avoid confusion, however, it can still be good to use double quotes.